# Centering or doing 2 div at same size with other div(s)

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a problem with doing 2 div (*.profile-spotify*, *.profile-games*) at same size with *.profile-card* and *.profile-details* or centering them. I tried with justify center, margin auto and others but it didn't work.

Here's the markup structure:

```
<div class="user-content">
    <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 mt-3">
        <!-- Profile Card -->
        <div class="profile-card text-center m-auto">
            ...
        </div>
        <!-- End of Profile Card -->
        
        <!-- Profile Details -->
        <div class="profile-details text-white m-auto mt-3 lg:mt-0">
            ...
        </div>
        <!-- End of Profile Details -->
    </div>
    <!-- Spotify Activity -->
    <div class="profile-spotify mt-5 mb-5 m-auto">
        <div class="profile-spotify-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="profile-spotify-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Spotify Activity -->
    
    <!-- Game Activity -->
    <div class="profile-games mt-5 mb-5 m-auto">
        <div class="profile-game">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Game Activity -->
</div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
...
.user-content {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.user-content .profile-card {
background: #1f2325;
width: 15rem;
}
.user-content .profile-spotify, .user-content .profile-games {
background: #1f2325;
max-width: 30rem;
}
.user-content .profile-spotify-header {
background: #21d363;
padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
}
...
```

[image: The problem]

https://codepen.io/wYonut/pen/eYrQoRr

I want them like this:
[image: An exemple for what I want]

Comment: Why don't you set the width of `.profile-details` to 14.5rem for example, or decrease the width of your lower blocks. The problem is clearly in different widths of the top and bottom blocks

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex;` on parent and `flex:1;` on children.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    first <br> content
  </div>
  <div>second content</div>
</div>
```